# Umbraco: Multiple approvals after upgrading to 6.2.6

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

Umbraco 6

Hi there,

We've just upgraded our Umbraco site from v6.1.6 to v6.2.6. Our Admins have noticed that they are receiving 3 approval emails each time that an editor submits (in v 6.1.6 they only received 1 approval email). Is this a known issue, or is there anywhere that we could look to see where this is set?

Thanks Ben

Comment: If you haven't already, it's worth searching for the issue or posting it on the issue tracker: http://issues.umbraco.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of that being an issue on 6.2.6. You can check the database and see if the alerts are configured multiple times (they shouldn't be though, unless something has gone haywire)?

The table this info lives in is: umbracoUser2NodeNotify. You can check in there to see if users are configured to get multiple alerts.